# How to find the missing end, or maybe too many ends in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following error in a very short Ruby program:

```
(repl):8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
(repl):11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Here is the code:

```
def three_digit_format(n) 
  digits = n.to_s.length 
  string = n.to_s
  number_of_zeros = 3 - digits.to_i
   while number_of_zeros > 0 
     string += "0"
     number_of_zeros--
   end
end
```

It seems like this should be straightforward but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: looks ok... can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: I'd recommend using a Ruby lint program. There are several out there, and they can be integrated with decent editors. They'd immediately show the error, along with suggesting improvements to your coding style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ruby `++` and `--` operators don't exist. Go for

```
number_of_zeros -= 1
```

Comment: Yea got it thanks. I just started ruby a week ago, coming from javascript.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct way in Ruby `number_of_zeros--`

Please use `number_of_zeros -= 1`